# Share data between apache modules

Tags: apache, apache-modules

Is there a way to share data between apache modules?

Example:

1. `mod_a` makes a calculation and gets some number as a result.
2. `mod_b` makes another calculation and I need to sum it with the result from `mod_a`.

What is the way to do it?

I've tried to pass it through `r->notes` table, but with no success. The data from both modules is seen in the log, but they don't see each others data.

P.S. `mod_b` always do the job after `mod_a` had finished processing within a single request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case `mod_a` was setting the value inside apache's internal redirect, so there was another request record 'r' (and 'notes' table). The solution was changing `r->notes` to `r->prev->notes` to set the value into original request table.